# Is my event raised in the correct aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm pretty new to implementing a DDD + CQRS + event sourcing system. The following is the business context I'm modelling:

> A `User` can create an `Organization`. An `Organization` can have
> multiple `Members`. `Members` can either be `Regular` members or
> `Admin` members. The user that creates the organization is by default
> the first `Admin`.

In particular, im trying to represent the act of creating an organization in an implementation that is domain rich. The following is what I have so far.

```js
class User extends Aggregate {
  constructor(
    public readonly id: UserId,
    public readonly name: Name,
    public readonly email: Email
  ) {
    super(id);
  }

  createOrganization(orgId: OrgId, name: Name) {
    const creator = new Member(orgId, MemberRoles.Admin, this.id);
    return new Organization(orgId, name, [creator]);
  }
}
```

```js
class Organization extends Aggregate {
  public readonly members: Member[];
  public readonly name: Name;

  constructor(
    id: OrgId,
    name: Name,
    members: Member[],
  ) {
    super(id);
    this.name = name;
    this.members = members
  }

  addMember(member) { /**/}
  removeMember(memberId) { /**/}
}
```

I like the fact that I have a `.createOrganization()` method on the User class since it illustrates the fact that a user has the ability to do so. But where should I raise `UserCreatedOrganizationEvent`? Should I do it in the User class? Is it not wrong to create events in one aggregate (`User`) which would then be used to directly hydrated another aggregate (`Organization`)? I keep hearing that each aggregate should hydrate themselves from their own events to ensure invariants are always ensured. Then does it make more sense to have a static `create` method on the organization? But I can't raise an event associated to my aggregate from a `static` method. Any thoughts on this would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the Organization aggregate as part of your User aggregate is wrong because the User aggregate ends up understanding the intricacies of the Organization aggregate. They end up being tightly coupled.

The Admin user is just one of the many details that go into creating the organization. I would think of it as an Authentication/Authorization concern that would validate if the user performing the action should be allowed to go through it.

And yes, typically, you would create a factory method (a class method) within the Organization aggregate that would instantiate the Aggregate and raise an event ***on the instantiated aggregate object***. The factory method would be invoked by a Command Handler, handling the command to create an organization.

Think of the contra argument to clearly understand why the user creating the organization via the user aggregate is not sustainable. Technically, **every single** action in your application would be performed by a user. That does not mean that the user aggregate is responsible for all other Aggregates in the system.

Comment: If you raise the "create event" in the factory, you will have to instantiate an invalid aggregate. I want to avoid that. I want my objects to always be valid.

Comment: Why would the aggregate be invalid?

Comment: Because you are applying the event after the object has instantiated. It's only after applying the event do the properties get set.

Comment: There is a bit of confusion here in the flow, I think. I was talking about raising events once the aggregate's invariants were satisfied.You seem to be talking about applying events, but how did the events come to be without an aggregate being valid?

Comment: Do you mind putting up some code so that I can understand what you mean?